# IndexedDB video binary file is corrupt

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm saving a bunch of videos to IndexedDB, then displaying them again for an offline version of an app.  I have an issue however where occasionally one blob video file will become corrupt.  My investigation so far has revealed:

- the video file is not corrupt because it's been re-rendered and is rendered in the same way as the other videos
- the issue is when saving to the DB rather than retrieving from the DB
- the issue occurs when running through both my local server and a remote server, it happens on the remote server more however
- the issue seems to happen randomly i.e. I do not change any other variables to cause this issue

So I'm a bit stuck now, anyone have any ideas as to what the problem may be?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexedDB is not intended for storing big files and that is root of the problem. One direction where you can take a look is the file system API, unfortunately this API only works in [Chrome (Nov 2014)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem).

Comment: Useful answer, thought I may get an answer like this but still trying to explore the possibilities, unfortunately the app needs to work as cross-platform.  So either I'm stuck with this and try to enhance it, or I explore an entirely new alternative such as utilising Drop-box.

Comment: what kind of app are you creating, if it's a mobile maybe you can use the storage layer of each of the platforms?

Comment: It is an HTML "web app" so restricted to HTML capabilities as far as I know. This app has suffered from incorrect identification of required technologies at the start in some ways.